# Performance of operator| vs operators+

Tags: c++, math, boolean-operations

Is there any major difference between | and + that would affect a code's performance in the long run? or are both O(1)? the code i am working with is something like this:

```
uint64_t dostuff(uint64_t a,uint64_t b){
        // the max values of the inputs are 2^32 - 1

        // lots of stuff involving boolean operators
        // that have no way of being substituted by 
        // arithmetic operators

        return (a << 32) + b;
        //or
        return (a << 32) | b;
}
```

the code will be used many times, so i want to speed it up as much as possible.

Comment: this is silly.  have you profiled you're code yet to see if this matters at all?

Comment: this is part of a cryptography algorithm. speed is sort of nice to have

Comment: The time difference cannot be measured using `O()` notation.  If you need to set bits, use '|'.  If you need to add bits, use '+'.  A PRIMARY DIFFERENCE IS THAT '|' DOES NOT PERFORM CARRY, BUT '+' DOES.

Comment: @Thomas you do realize that the carry has no effect in this instance.

Comment: @trutheality:  I speak for the general case.  I know that performing initializations like this will bite back later.  I prefer safe and correct programming over micro-optimizations.  People who do this kind of optimization should be aware that addition may perform bitwise carry whereas an arithmetic OR will not.

Comment: This is a nonsensical question. `+` and `|` do different things. Code for what makes your code correct, not fast. If you need bitwise-or, use that, otherwise use add. @calc: Your comment doesn't answer his question, let me ask again: Have you *profiled* your code yet to see if this matters at all? If not, see the first part of my answer. Of course speed is "nice to have", that means nothing when it comes to actually deciding what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No performance difference on any modern computer.

The two operators have different meaning though. If the bit is already set, `|` will do nothing, but `+` will clear the bit and all the following non-zero bits and set the next zero bit to 1.

Comment: yes, i know. but their results are the same thing in this situation

Comment: @ybungalobill Right, but the 32 bit shift and the condition that `the max values of the inputs are 2^32 - 1` means that those bits will always be 0, right?

Comment: yes. thus, the last 32 bits of the shifted a will allow for the `or`ed b to be 'inserted' directly in

Comment: @calccrypto @trutheality: fine, it doesn't contradict what I said about the general case. And I answered the question.

Comment: On any modern computer? What about CELL-processors that are altivec/SIMD-optimized and have only one general-purpose register? The performance difference is clearly measurable and an issue if performing very high amounts of calculations. Unless, of course, you consider the cell-processor to be old.

Comment: @Simon if performance increases of this miniscular magnitude were in order to cell phone applications theay'd all be written in assembler.

Comment: @johnathon: I'm not talking about cell phone applications, I'm talking about CELL processors. Such as the one in the PS3. Similar processors exist in modern GPU's which essentially are optimized for math operations and not bitwise operations. Such processors tend to have only one general purpose register and thus can't handle two-register-bitwise operations. In such cases the values have to be loaded to altivec-registers by masking them, then performing the operation on those registers and masking them back into the general purpose register.

Answer (score 3):

Both are certainly O(1) since O(1) means a constant.  They are probably not the same constant.  Big Oh notation is meant to understand asymptotic behavior independent of constants.

Oh yeah, one more thing.  *Always* profile before you optimize.  You'll find out very quickly that time isn't being spent where you think.  *Always*!

Answer (score 2):

Use `|`.

`+` can only add to the operation time par obvious reasons.

Comment: | is a bitwise operation. + takes extra steps.
The extra step may include using 2s complement to add with.

There may be an optimization involved if something notices that one of the operands is 0, or if there are no overlapping 1s. However if there are overlapping 1s, then additional work has to be done to add the values.

Comment: The worst effect of using + would be if the execution time depended on the data and leaked secret information.

Answer (score 1):

Both are a single instruction. As for electronic propagation times, no idea which one is faster.

You can test for speed yourself, I guess, but seeing as the difference will probably be linear (if detectable at all), and affected by noisy factors, it may be a bit difficult.

Comment: The time difference between an adder circuit and an arithmetic OR operation may be so negligible that measuring requires more precise instruments than a PC or profiler.  Usually, this small of a time difference requires a high performance oscilloscope.

Comment: @Thomas wow, man! My most sincere sideways quiet admiration look!

Comment: @Thomas, @Santiago: A bitwise OR involves independent combinatorial logic for each bit position; an adder involves a carry chain (or carry-look ahead logic), which implies a greater overall propagation time.  However, on a CPU, they will clearly both  have been designed to execute well within one clock cycle!  In other words, the difference cannot be discerned by the programmer.

Comment: There are platforms which have issues with resolving dynamic bitwise operations (modern RISC focused on vectorized-maths). In some occations, it is definetly measurable.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer here is not trying to predict which one is better but benchmark it or check the assembly code. I would guess that both will be optimized to the same instruction and in any case the number of CPU cycles taken by both could be equal.

But I strongly suggest you to check ASM and benchmark both solutions.

Comment: They certainly can't be optimised to the same instruction here, because they mean different things. The compiler doesn't read the comments!

Comment: They will use different instructions, but both are of the kind that executes 3-4 ops per clock at 3 GHz times 4-8 cores on  a chip. Now much time can we possibly gain from an "optimization" here? 1/10 of a nanosecond on one core? Will anyone notice?

Answer (score 1):

If there's any advantage, it's going to be in favor of the `or`. In reality, however, there's unlikely to be any difference on any reasonably modern CPU (or even anything but a *really* ancient one).

Basically, an `or` just sets the bit, and that's all. One two-input `or` gate is all that's needed, so you get exactly one gate of propagation delay.

An adder is a bit more complex: computing the current bit requires a three-input XOR. An XOR is normally composed to two levels of gates. In addition, it generates a carry, that has to be used as an input to the adder for the next bit. A "ripple carry adder", therefore, needs as many clock cycles as there are bits being added. There are cleverer ways of handling the problem where you handle carries separately from the rest of the addition, so you get a lower propagation delay, but in the worst case, even these don't help.

Most of that only matters if you're designing a CPU yourself though. If you're using a typical CPU, the gates in the functional units are running fast enough that it can/will do a full add in one clock cycle. Some reasonably recent ones can even do two adds per clock cycle in a single functional unit.

Answer (score 0):

The `|` and '+` are different mathematical operations.
Given the equations:

```
  unsigned int y = 2 + 2;
  unsigned int z = 2 | 2;
```

will yield different answers.

Technically, the `|' operation is faster since it only uses OR gates inside the processor.  The addition operation requires more gates.

The performance gained by using '|' over '+' is usually wasted by the time required to fetch data into and out of the processor.  In otherwords, the net performance is negligible. (The time difference is usually in the range of nanoseconds.)

However, the maintenance time between the two forms may be greater.  When one is needing arithmetic rather than bit twiddling (or vice versa), trying to find this runtime error can be great.

Use the proper operator for the proper purpose.  Give the testing and maintenance groups a break.  This kind of micro-optimization is not worthwhile.

Comment: exactly not what i was asking

Comment: If you notice, he purposefully offsets one number ensuring that the numbers are on opposite sides of a bigger memory area. Therefore the bits will never overlap, and `|` and `+` will output the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is platform-specific (and likely compiler-specific). On the SPU's on the PS3, dynamic OR's are quite expensive if I remember correctly. I'm not sure of the numbers but I think that it ends up by dividing it into multiple operations, causing the cost to expand to several instructions. On x86/x64 or most modern CISC it is quite likely that either one is just one instruction and is very unlikely to cause any pipeline stalls or other costly operations.

Edit:
The reason for the cost is because the Cell processor only has one general-purpose-register which means that it can't load both variables into standard registers and perform the optimization. Instead the values have to be loaded into the altivec-register set where the operation has to be done, the result then has to be fetched from the altivec registers into the gpr by a mask in order to retrieve the result.

If you are pushing these operations onto a PS3 or the GPU on any modern computer, you might want to look into how those processors behave. The GPU's might also have similar issues since they're also RISC-processors dedicated towards SIMD-operations.